# Is there a monospaced font similar to GothamNarrow-Book?

Tags: fonts, typography

I have a timer running on a video overlay in a mobile application. The font used throughout the app is **GothamNarrow-Book**.

While it looks nice, it is distracting to see the running timer constantly changing its width. Here is a sample of what the font looks like:

[image]

I'm open to all suggestions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need a different font, what you need is to use lining or tabular figures, which are numbers designed to line up with each other when displaying data. 
Apparently [Gotham has tabular figures](http://www.typography.com/fonts/gotham/features/gotham-numerics), you just need to activate them through openType.

Answer (score 3):

**Check out [Source Code Pro at Google Fonts](https://www.google.com/fonts/specimen/Source+Code+Pro).**
It's a broad family with an accompanying non-monospace font: Source Sans Pro. The two make up a very well-designed system from veteran type designer Paul Hunt.

[image]

Comment: Looks good but I'm not sure how the 0's with the dots in the middle will go over with everyone here.

Comment: As the name implies, it's designed to work well for code. Slashed or dotted zeroes are common now since monospace fonts don't have many other uses. Tabular figures, of course, are another matter.